# Web Deploy Impersonation (Management Service Delegation) does not work

Tags: impersonation, delegation, webdeploy, dac

I’m trying to use web deploy to deploy my dacpac package, which comes to executing some sql scripts.
I have local windows account called .\DeploymentService, which is in local Administrators group, which I want to own the database and execute scripts.

For that - I configure delegation accordingly - In Management Service Delegation I set "Specific User" for dbDacFx rule = .\DeploymentService providing password
[image: Management Service Delegation - for dbDacFx]

I create according serveradmin login in SQL Server. My WMSvc executed under LOCAL SERVICE account.

I use the following command line parameters for deployment:

> msdeploy.exe
>   -verb:sync
>   -source:dbDacFx="C:\Main\Src\Community.DB\bin\Debug\Community.DB.dacpac"
>   -dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=.;Database=CommunityInt; Integrated Security=true",computername=”https://Community02:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default
>   Web Site”,username=.\DeploymentService,password=*************,authType=basic
>   -allowuntrusted

I execute it on my PC, where destination is different PC.

However this fails with error “Invalid Handle” or “Class name not found” depending on do I have “Local service” login with public role in my SQL Server created.

Expected behavior: 
When I set user name in Management Service Delegation to specific account, I expect MSDeploy to be executed under the account I specified.

Actual behavior:
I traced using SQL profiler in target environment and I found out that WMSvc executes msdeploy under its process account (LOCAL SERVICE) instead of .\DeploymentService, and that’s why script execution fails. If in SQL server I have LOCAL SERVICE account mapped to serveradmin role, then it works fine. If I execute WMSvc under .\DeploymentService account, it also works fine.

**So basically there is NO WAY TO USE "User Name" in Management Service Delegation - It just does not matter what you set up there - it gives no effect.**

Does any one know how to make that work?

Keywords: WebDeploy, WMSvc, dbDacFx, Impersonation, Delegation

Comment: One weird quick question... if you want the connection to use the DeploymentService creds, is there a reason you've set it up for SpecificUser rather than just leaving IdentityType as "CurrentUser" (since that's who you're connecting as anyway)?

Comment: I tried that as well - does not change anything.
Also I assume "CurrentUser" should mean the user that was authenticated to WMSvc - which will not work in case I use IIS User for authentication.

Comment: I contacted to MS Deploy developers, they confirmed it is a bug, which probably will be fixed in next release (WebDeploy 4), next year

Comment: Any news on WebDeploy 4, or is this another abandoned Microsoft technology?

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I'm sorry to hear that you are running into this issue. I wanted to let you know that we have a bug in the dbDacFx provider/MSDeploy which is preventing SQL Auth to work when used with the dbDacFx provider in WMSvc scenarios.

We have not yet received enough feedback regarding this to warrant servicing MSDeploy in order to unblock this. If you are impacted by this the best thing to do is to create an entry at http://aspnet.uservoice.com and vote it up. If we get enough votes then we can consider shipping an update to unblock this. Sorry for the bad news.